# Why is the resolution of my website's screen not properly fitting the screen size on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, resolution, screen-resolution

So at first the resolution was perfectly matching up with the mobile devices width however after changing the background image, for some odd reason the width all of a sudden doesn't fit the exact device length now. I tried resetting the branch to a point where the resolution was fine but it still doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

As you can see in my screen there's some white space on the right side of the screen, I'm trying to remove that part.

[image]

[image]

[image]

It also doesn't seem to be a margin or padding issue as the html entity itself isn't up to the width of the device

[A link to the github repo](https://github.com/Gamingapple0/Sanskar_Handicrafts)

Can anyone help me with this? I'm willing to provide more information if needed

Here's my index file

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Sanskar Handicrafts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'website/fontawesome-5.5/css/all.min.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'website/slick/slick.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'website/slick/slick-theme.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'website/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'website/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'website/css/style.css' %}" />

<style>
  
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

  #view > a{
    color: #FFF;
  }
  .flex-box{  
    display: flex;  
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
  .flex-img{
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 400px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.flex-text{
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 500px;
}
.flex-rev{
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

</style>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <!-- Hero section -->
    <section id="infinite" class="text-white tm-font-big tm-parallax">
      <!-- Navigation -->            
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md tm-navbar scroll" id="tmNav">
        <div class="tm-next">
          <a href="#infinite" class="navbar-brand" style="background: white;color: #369;width: 100%;padding-left: 10px;">
            Sanskar Handicrafts</a>
      </div> 
        <div class="container" style="display:grid; padding-left: 0; margin-left: 0;">   
  
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="fas fa-bars navbar-toggler-icon"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="#infinite">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="#whatwedo">About Us</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="making" id="making">Making</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link tm-nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>                    
            </ul>
          </div>        
        </div>
      </nav>

      <!-- <div class="tm-next tm-intro-next">
        <a href="#whatwedo" class="text-center tm-down-arrow-link">
          <i class="fas fa-2x fa-arrow-down tm-down-arrow"></i>
        </a>
      </div>       -->
    </section>
    <br>

    <section id="whatwedo" class="tm-section-pad-top" style="padding-top:50px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
      
      <div class="container">
            <div class="row tm-content-box"><!-- first row -->
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                    <div class="tm-intro-text-container">
                        <h2 class="tm-text-primary mb-4 tm-section-title">About Us</h2>
                        <p class="mb-4 tm-intro-text">
                          Handicrafts of Nepal itself is needless of any introduction. In every corner of Kathmandu valley, you will find masterpieces of crafts and arts. The skill and techniques and excellent craftsmanship have been handed down from generation to generation, which represents the talent and skill of craftsmen and reflects the social, religious, and cultural values found in different parts of the country.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                  <div class="tm-intro-text-container">
                      <p class="mb-4 tm-intro-text">
                        Handicrafts of Nepal, itself is needless of any introduction. In each and every
corner of Kathmandu valley you will find the masterpieces of crafts and arts.
The skill and techniques, the excellent craftsmanship have been handed down
from generation to generation which represents the talent and skill of
craftsmen and also reflects the social, religious and cultural values found in
different parts of the country.

<b>Sanskar Handicrafts</b> is the place where you might find the statues with
excellence craftmanship. <b>Sanskar Handicrafts</b> is a gallery affiliated to <b>Siddhi
  Hastakala Udhyog</b>, a renowned name for fine arts and crafts.</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div><!-- first row -->
            
            <div class="flex-box">
              <div><img src="{% static 'website/img/Gramps.JPG' %}" alt="" class="flex-img"></div>
              <div class="flex-text">
                  <h5>Our respected grandfather</h5>
                  <p>The legendary artisan, Late Mr. <b>SIDDHI RAJ SHAKYA</b>, needs no introduction. He is a big name, a brand, in the world of arts and crafts. His work and his contribution to art and culture is impeccable.</p>                            
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-box flex-rev">
              <div><img src="{% static 'website/img/Man1.jpg' %}" alt="" class="flex-img"></div>
              <div class="flex-text">
                  <h5>Senior Sculptor of our firm</h5>
                  <p>His son, our father, Senior Sculptor of our firm, Siddhi Hastakala Udhyog, Mr. <b>Siddhi Ratna Shakya</b>, well inherited the skill of sculpting, the talent.</p>                            
              </div>
          </div>                              
          <div class="flex-box">
            <div><img src="{% static 'website/img/Man0.JPG' %}" alt="" class="flex-img"></div>
            <div class="flex-text">
                <h5>Proprietor of Siddhi Hastakala Udhyog</h5>
                <p>The skill, techniques, and talent have been passed down from generation to generation. His grandson, Mr. <b>Sabin Shakya</b>, being the 4th generation to this elite group, proprietor of Siddhi Hastakala Udhyog, has been continuing the family's legacy. </p>                            
            </div>
        </div>                              

        </div>
      
    </section>
    
    <section id="testimonials" class="tm-section-pad-top tm-parallax-2" style="background-image: none; display: none;">      
      
    </section>
    
    <section id="gallery" class="tm-section-pad-top" style="padding-top: 30px">
      <div class="container tm-container-gallery">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="text-center col-12">
              <h2 class="tm-text-primary tm-section-title mb-4">Gallery</h2>
              <p class="mx-auto tm-section-desc">
                Praesent sed pharetra lorem, blandit convallis mi. Aenean ornare elit ac metus lacinia, sed iaculis nibh semper. Pellentesque est urna, lobortis eu arcu a, aliquet tristique urna.
              </p>
          </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                 <div class="mx-auto tm-gallery-container">
                    <div class="grid tm-gallery">
                        {% for image in images %}
                      <a href="{{image.img.url}}">
                        <figure class="effect-honey tm-gallery-item">
                          <img src="{{image.img.url}}" alt="{{image.name}}" class="img-fluid">
                        </figure>
                      </a>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>

      <div id='view'>
       <a href="gallery"> View All</a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Contact -->
    <section id="contact" class="tm-section-pad-top tm-parallax-2" style="padding-top:80px">
    
      <div class="container tm-container-contact">
        
        <div class="row">
            
            <div class="text-center col-12">
                <h2 class="tm-section-title mb-4">Contact Us</h2>
                <p class="mb-5">
                  Proin enim orci, tincidunt quis suscipit in, placerat nec est. Vestibulum posuere faucibus posuere. Quisque aliquam velit eget leo blandit egestas. Nulla id posuere felis, quis tristique nulla.
                </p><br>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
              <form action="/submitted" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="tm-input" required />
                <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email" class="tm-input" required />
                <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="8" placeholder="Message" class="tm-input" required></textarea>
                <button type="submit" class="btn tm-btn-submit">Submit</button>
              </form>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                
                <div class="contact-item">
                  <a rel="nofollow" href="mailto:mail@company.com" class="item-link">
                      <i class="far fa-2x fa-envelope mr-4"></i>
                      <span class="mb-0">mail@company.com</span>
                  </a>              
                </div>
                
                <div class="contact-item">
                  <a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.google.com/maps" class="item-link">
                      <i class="fas fa-2x fa-map-marker-alt mr-4"></i>
                      <span class="mb-0">Our Location</span>
                  </a>              
                </div>
                
                <div class="contact-item">
                  <a rel="nofollow" href="tel:0100200340" class="item-link">
                      <i class="fas fa-2x fa-phone-square mr-4"></i>
                      <span class="mb-0">255-662-5566</span>
                  </a>              
                </div>
                
                <div class="contact-item">&nbsp;</div>
            
            </div>
            
            
        </div><!-- row ending -->
        
      </div>


        <footer class="text-center small tm-footer">
          <p class="mb-0">
          Copyright &copy; 2021 Company Name 
          
        </footer>

    </section>
    
    <script src="{% static 'website/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'website/slick/slick.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'website/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'website/js/easing.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'website/js/jquery.singlePageNav.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'website/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
      
      function getOffSet(){
        var _offset = 450;
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

        if(windowHeight > 500) {
          _offset = 400;
        } 
        if(windowHeight > 680) {
          _offset = 300
        }
        if(windowHeight > 830) {
          _offset = 210;
        }

        return _offset;
      }

      function setParallaxPosition($doc, multiplier, $object){
        var offset = getOffSet();
        var from_top = $doc.scrollTop(),
          bg_css = 'center ' +(multiplier * from_top - offset) + 'px';
        $object.css({"background-position" : bg_css });
      }

      // Parallax function
      // Adapted based on https://codepen.io/roborich/pen/wpAsm        
      var background_image_parallax = function($object, multiplier, forceSet){
        multiplier = typeof multiplier !== 'undefined' ? multiplier : 0.5;
        multiplier = 1 - multiplier;
        var $doc = $(document);
        // $object.css({"background-attatchment" : "fixed"});

        if(forceSet) {
          setParallaxPosition($doc, multiplier, $object);
        } else {
          $(window).scroll(function(){          
            setParallaxPosition($doc, multiplier, $object);
          });
        }
      };

      var background_image_parallax_2 = function($object, multiplier){
        multiplier = typeof multiplier !== 'undefined' ? multiplier : 0.5;
        multiplier = 1 - multiplier;
        var $doc = $(document);
        $object.css({"background-attachment" : "fixed"});
        
        $(window).scroll(function(){
          if($(window).width() > 768) {
            var firstTop = $object.offset().top,
                pos = $(window).scrollTop(),
                yPos = Math.round((multiplier * (firstTop - pos)) - 186);              

            var bg_css = 'center ' + yPos + 'px';

            $object.css({"background-position" : bg_css });
          } else {
            $object.css({"background-position" : "center" });
          }
        });
      };
      
      $(function(){
        // Hero Section - Background Parallax
        background_image_parallax($(".tm-parallax"), 0.30, false);
        background_image_parallax_2($("#contact"), 0.80);   
        background_image_parallax_2($("#testimonials"), 0.80);   
        
        // Handle window resize
        window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
          background_image_parallax($(".tm-parallax"), 0.30, true);
        }, true);

        // Detect window scroll and update navbar
        $(window).scroll(function(e){          
          if($(document).scrollTop() > 120) {
            $('.tm-navbar').addClass("scroll");
          }
        });
        
        // Close mobile menu after click 
        $('#tmNav a').on('click', function(){
          $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('show'); 
        })

        // Scroll to corresponding section with animation
        $('#tmNav').singlePageNav({
          'easing': 'easeInOutExpo',
          'speed': 600
        });        
        
        // Add smooth scrolling to all links
        // https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp
        $("a").on('click', function(event) {
          if (this.hash !== "") {
            event.preventDefault();
            var hash = this.hash;

            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 600, 'easeInOutExpo', function(){
              window.location.hash = hash;
            });
          } // End if
        });

        // Pop up
        $('.tm-gallery').magnificPopup({
          delegate: 'a',
          type: 'image',
          gallery: { enabled: true }
        });

        $('.tm-testimonials-carousel').slick({
          dots: true,
          prevArrow: false,
          nextArrow: false,
          infinite: false,
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          responsive: [
            {
              breakpoint: 992,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 768,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2
              }
            }, 
            {
              breakpoint: 480,
              settings: {
                  slidesToShow: 1
              }                 
            }
          ]
        });

        // Gallery
        $('.tm-gallery').slick({
          dots: true,
          infinite: false,
          slidesToShow: 5,
          slidesToScroll: 2,
          responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 1199,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 4,
              slidesToScroll: 2
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 991,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 3,
              slidesToScroll: 2
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 767,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2,
              slidesToScroll: 1
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1
            }
          }
        ]
        });
      });
    </script>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
        $('ul.slick-dots').remove()
      })
      let url = 'http://139.59.20.1/'
      $('#making').click(function(){
        window.location.href = url + "making"
      })
      $('#view').click(function(){
        window.location.href = url + "gallery"
      })
    </script>
    <style>
      a.slick-slide{
        /* max-width: 220px; */
      }
      img.img-fluid{
        min-width: 220px;
        max-width: 200px;
        max-height: 300px;
      }
    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my style.css

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,300,400,500,700,900");

body {
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #707070;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: #38B;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #D40;
}

a:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px 32px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ced4da;
}

blockquote {
  font-size: 0.86em;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}

.tm-section-pad-top {
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.tm-content-box {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.tm-text-primary {
  color: #37A;
}

.tm-font-big {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.tm-btn-primary {
  color: white;
  background-color: #369;
  padding: 14px 30px;
}

.tm-btn-primary:hover,
.tm-btn-primary:focus {
  color: white;
  background-color: #38B;
}

/* Navbar */

.tm-navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.tm-navbar.scroll {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9ecef;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.9rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-brand:hover,
.tm-navbar.scroll .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #38B;
}

.tm-navbar.scroll .navbar-brand {
  color: #369;
}

.nav-item {
  list-style: none;
}

.tm-nav-link {
  color: white;
}

.tm-navbar.scroll .tm-nav-link {
  color: #369;
}

.tm-navbar.scroll .tm-nav-link:hover,
.tm-navbar.scroll .tm-nav-link.current,
.tm-nav-link:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #369;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.tm-navbar.scroll .navbar-toggler {
  border: 1px solid #707070;
}

.tm-navbar.scroll .navbar-toggler-icon {
  color: #707070;
}

/* Hero */

#infinite {
    background-color: #222;
  background-image: url(../img/infinite-loop-04.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 375px;
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-height: 600px) and (min-width: 1920px) {
  #infinite {
    background-size: cover;
  }
}

@media (min-height: 830px) {
  #infinite {
    background-position: center -210px;
  }
}

@media (min-height: 680px) and (max-height: 829px) {
  #infinite {
    background-position: center -300px;
  }
}

@media (min-height: 500px) and (max-height: 679px) {
  #infinite {
    background-position: center -400px;
  }
}

@media (max-height: 499px) {
  #infinite {
    background-position: center -450px;
  }
}

.tm-hero-text-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tm-hero-text-container-inner {
  margin-top: -90px;
}

.tm-hero-title {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333;
}

.tm-hero-subtitle {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333;
}

.tm-intro-next {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

@media (max-height: 480px) {
  .tm-hero-text-container-inner {
    margin-top: -40px;
  }

  .tm-intro-next {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
}

.tm-down-arrow-link {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 18%;
}

.tm-down-arrow {
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #357;
    padding: 15px 40px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.tm-down-arrow:hover,
.tm-down-arrow:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #37A;
  padding: 20px 50px;
}

/* Introduction */

#introduction {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.tm-section-title {
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.tm-intro-text {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.tm-icon {
  display: block;
  color: #37A;
}

.tm-continue {
    padding: 20px 0 30px 0;
}

/* Testimonials */
#testimonials {
  color: white;
  background-image: url(../img/infinite-loop-03.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  #testimonials {
    background-image: url(../img/infinite-loop-03-mobile.jpg);
  }
}

.tm-testimonials-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.tm-bg-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(20, 70, 80, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.tm-testimonials-carousel {
  max-width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tm-testimonial-item {
  max-width: 290px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-right: 35px;
}

.tm-testimonial-item img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.tm-testimonial-item figcaption {
  text-align: right;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

/* Work */

.tm-section-desc {
  max-width: 650px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.tm-gallery-container {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.tm-gallery-item {
}

.slick-dots {
  bottom: -65px;
}

.slick-dots li {
  margin: 0 13px;
}

.slick-dots li button:hover:before,
.slick-dots li button:focus:before,
.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #3ba0dd;
}

.tm-testimonials-carousel .slick-dots li button:before {
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.tm-testimonials-carousel .slick-dots li button:hover:before,
.tm-testimonials-carousel .slick-dots li button:focus:before,
.tm-testimonials-carousel .slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}

.slick-dots li button:before {
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Hover Effect */
/* Common style */
.grid figure {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #3085a3;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.grid figure img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-width: 200px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.grid figure figcaption {
  padding: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.grid figure figcaption::before,
.grid figure figcaption::after {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.grid figure figcaption,
.grid figure figcaption > a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Anchor will cover the whole item by default */
/* For some effects it will show as a button */
.grid figure figcaption > a {
  z-index: 1000;
  text-indent: 200%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.grid figure h2 {
  word-spacing: -0.15em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.grid figure h2 span {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.grid figure h2,
.grid figure p {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid figure p {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 68.5%;
}

/*---------------*/
/***** Honey *****/
/*---------------*/

figure.effect-honey {
  background: #4a3753;
  max-width: 220px;
}

figure.effect-honey img {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s;
}

figure.effect-honey:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

figure.effect-honey figcaption::before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #38C;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
}

figure.effect-honey h2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
}

figure.effect-honey h2 i {
  font-style: normal;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
}

figure.effect-honey figcaption::before,
figure.effect-honey h2 {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
}

figure.effect-honey:hover figcaption::before,
figure.effect-honey:hover h2,
figure.effect-honey:hover h2 i {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.tm-container-gallery {
    padding-top: 30px;
    }

/* Contact */

#contact {
  color: white;
  background-color: #001828;
  /* background-image: url(../img/infinite-loop-03.jpg); */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 980px;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.contact-item {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.item-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item-link i,
.item-link span {
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.item-link:hover i,
.item-link:hover span {
  color: #3496d8;
}

.tm-input {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    width: 90%;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
}

.tm-btn-submit {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #369;
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.tm-btn-submit:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #38B;
}

::placeholder {
  /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: white;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: white;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: white;
}

.tm-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.tm-footer a {
    color: #fff;
}

.tm-footer a:hover {
    color: #9CF;
}

.tm-footer-link {
  color: white;
}

.tm-footer-link:hover,
.tm-footer-link:focus {
  color: #38B;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.9;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .tm-intro-text-container {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }

  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1275px;
  }

  .tm-container-gallery {
    max-width: 1290px;
  }

  .tm-container-contact {
    max-width: 1063px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .tm-intro-text-container {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  .tm-intro-img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  .tm-btn-submit {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {

  .navbar-nav {
    max-width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
  }

  .navbar-collapse {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

  .navbar-collapse .nav-link {
    color: #707070;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .tm-gallery-container {
    max-width: 220px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  .tm-gallery-container-2 {
    max-width: 350px;
  }

  .slick-dots li {
    margin: 0 8px;
  }

  .tm-gallery-item {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Pls, provide the HTML and CSS code for it.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add your current code to see what happened exactly.

Comment: @ArchitGargi I have added the link to the github repo

Comment: @VishalKalansooriya What part of the code would you need? would the index page be enugh?

Comment: index.html file + style.css file

Comment: @VishalKalansooriya I have done it, can you please review it now, thanks.

Comment: Yes I did it now. Just try it and please tell me whether it works or not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `max-width: 500px;` from your flex-img class and add `width: 100%;` to it. Please refer to the below images for more information.

[image]

The above picture shows the error and the below picture shows the solution for it.

[image]

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Nope unfortunately doesn't work. Flex image is just used in 2 images, but my problem isn't just with the image but the whole index.html page doesn't fit the mobile phone's resolution. The other pages work fine though.

Comment: That images are the problem for that blank space. I just tried it going through inspect in your website (https://www.sanskarhandicrafts.com) and it works perfectly when I do the changes that I have mentioned earlier. Please check it again if you like.

Comment: No no that's not what I wanted to fix, I wanted to change the width of the text and the background image instead of the flex-img, because there's like an uneven white gap on the right side

Comment: I don't know why there is no gap on the right side of the website when I change the width of the flex-img. Look at this image. https://i.ibb.co/68tv7Hj/error1.png Can you mark me the places where you are having this trouble cause I can't understand what you are actually telling because for me, your site is working perfectly when I did that changes I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Try to zoom out it zooms out if you pinch the screen

Comment: I'm already zoomed out and in the normal view. Please show me your problem by taking a screenshot of that place and highlighting it.

Comment: I've added my screenshot, can you see it now?

Comment: Please listen to me.  I'm telling this for the fourth time. Look at this image. https://i.ibb.co/Np0btmt/aaaa.png In there can you see the image is wider than the width of your other elements which means 100% of your device width because you have set its max-width to 500px. But the size of your current viewport is only 375px. So it can't show that entire image in that place. So you should have to do the things I have told you without any changers. I'm sure that it works because I tried it on your website which is uploaded to the internet and it worked properly. Please think and try again.

Comment: So sorry I was stubborn with my own view, I tried it now it works, thankyou so much!

Comment: Oh it's okay. Glad to hear that finally it works :)